# Continuous deployment gitlab

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, jq

Line of my `.gitlab-ci.yml`

`IID=$(curl --verbose --request GET --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${CI_PUSH_TOKEN}" ${APP_REPO_URL}/merge_requests?author_id=xxxxxxxx\&search=${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA} | jq '.[0].iid')`

output jq: error (at :0): Cannot index object with number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the documentation on [Merge requests API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html) and [How to use the API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#how-to-use-the-api) to construct a properly formed cURL request with GitLab API before piping the result into `jq`.

There are a few things going on with your query.

First of all, according to the documentation, the `/merge_requests` endpoint will

> Get all merge requests the authenticated user has access to.

This means that `APP_REPO_URL` needs to be the GitLab instance URL followed by `/api/v4` and not the URL of the specific project.

```sh
curl "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/merge_requests"
```

If you need all merge requests for a given project, then you can use

```sh
curl "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/:id/merge_requests"
```

where `:id` is the id of your project. See more at [List project merge requests](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#list-project-merge-requests)

Then, the `search` attribute is expecting either a title or a description and not a commit SHA:

> Search merge requests against their title and description